# not applicable for the ' main.dart ' configuration

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

i couldn't run my flutter application on a real device neither on the emulator even thought the flutter sdk is installed and it's path is set does anybody knows what can be the cause of it ?
here's how it is shown in android studio[image]

when checked the project structure it says [image] how can i also fix this ?

here's the command that i made because they said that i should verifiy that my phone can be seen by the flutter sdk  and that i should make sure that there is no error left by the 'flutter doctor' command
but nothing did actually help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to get rid of that Android licenses and VS Code error.
Then on android studio, from the menu bar: "Tools > Device Manager > Create new device". Create a new virtual emulator from there and delete any old ones.

Also, I would recommend to ask for help after your "flutter doctor -v" comes out clean with "No issues found!".

Comment: it did not help , i have installed every requirement related to the 'flutter doctor ' command and I have created a new device but nothing have changed .

Comment: the solution was that i will just use vs code instead of android studio